# Make Linux reply to certain ARP requsts

Tags: linux, routing, arp

I’m trying to pull a certain routing stunt where I want my Linux server to respond to arp requests for `10.0.0.1` on `eth0`, although

- `10.0.0.1` is *not* the configured IP for `eth0` (in which case the kernel would do this nevertheless) and
- `10.0.0.1` is *not* routed to some other interface of this server (in which case arp proxying would help).

The effect should be that other devices on `eth0` would route packages to `10.0.0.1` to my server, where I can then handle them in `PREROUTING` and other tables.

Can I do that, preferably without an additional daemon?

---

As requested, here is my motivation (but note that this question is *not* about suggestions how to achieve this by different means – I really am interested in knowing if above is possibly, not whether it is sensible :-)).

Assume `10.0.0.1` to be a public IP address, and the only one routed to the machine in question. The system (`host`) contains a virtual machine (`guest`). I want `guest` to believe `10.0.0.1` is his, so giving it a different IP and doing nat is not what I want to do. Instead, I `host` to

- have another ip address (`192.168.0.1`), not publicly routed,
- act towards `eth0` as if it had `10.0.0.1`,
- redirect any access to `10.0.0.1:2222` to `192.168.0.1`, i.e. handle it locally,
- route any other traffic to `10.0.0.1` towards the virtual interface that `guest` is attached to.

This explains the two constraints in the question: The `guest` machine may not always be up, so the mentioned route will not always be there – this is what rules out Proxy ARP. Also, I cannot assing `10.0.0.1` to `eth0`, as it is really difficult to make Linux route a package away that is destined to an address that the kernel thinks is local. The `local` routing table has priority 0 according to `ip rule`, for instance.

Comment: What do you want the behavior of 10.0.0.1 to be when `guest` is down?

Comment: The redirect of `2222` still needs to work, so the arp replies need to be sent. Otherwise, packages to 10.0.0.1 may be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

What about using IP Aliases such as eth0:1 ?  That would cause the interface to respond to ARPs and allow you to manage its behavior with iptables.

Also, its not clear why proxy-arp won't help you here as you could interrupt the expected behavior with the iptables rules.

Can you explain more what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Elaborated my question.